# Evaluating $ \mathbb{P}(Y+X>a \cap X>b)$ when $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

This is a rather simple question: we have $X,Y$ jointly Bivariate Normally distributed, with $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ being their density. We're interested in the probabilities of the type:

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y+X>a \cap X>b) $$

The above can be evaluated via a double integral:

$$\int_{x=b}^{\infty} \int_{y=a-x}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy\,dx $$

**I am interested in evaluating the integral via the area of the $X,Y$ grid spanned by the integration domain.**

For an example, say that we set $b=0$ & $a=0$ so that we want to compute:

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y+X>0 \cap X>0)=\mathbb{P}(Y>-X \cap X>0) $$

This is quite easy: since $X>0$, we are only interested in the right-hand side of the cartesian $X,Y$ domain. Furthermore $y>-x$ carves out the bottom $1/4$ of the right-hand side domain, so we are left with $3/4$ of $1/2$, which is trivially $3/8$: because $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a cone centred on zero of the $X,Y$ Cartesian grid, by symmetry, the integral evaluates to $3/8$ by inspection.

**Question**: This might be completely trivial, but is there an easy way to use this approach for general $a$ and $b$? Setting $a = 2$ and $b = 1$, I was actually unable to figure out **what proportion of the Cartesian $X,Y$ grid is carved out and what proportion is left**. To figure out which part of the $X,Y$ grid is left, I transformed the problem into a single-integral as follows (the idea is that I compute the area below the line $y=2-x$ and then use this info as a stepping stone for further computation):

$$ \int_{x=1}^{\infty}(2-x)dx=\left[2x-0.5x^2 \right]_{1}^{\infty}=\infty $$

So that didn't take me anywhere, and I am not immediately able to see from the geometry how else to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
X \\ Y
\end{pmatrix} \sim 
N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_X \\ \mu_Y
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{XX} & \Sigma_{XY} \\
\Sigma_{XY} & \Sigma_{YY}
\end{pmatrix}\right)
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
X +Y \\ Y
\end{pmatrix} \sim 
N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_X + \mu_Y\\ \mu_Y
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{XX} + \Sigma_{YY} + 2\Sigma_{XY} & \Sigma_{XY} + \Sigma_{YY} \\
\Sigma_{XY} + \Sigma_{YY}& \Sigma_{YY}
\end{pmatrix}\right)
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, Tom. The approach you propose would work. However, I was asked the question in a recent interview and was told to evaluate the probability via evaluating the area of the $X,Y$ on which the domain sits. This was easy for the case where $\mathbb{P}(Y>(-X) \cap X>0)$, but I couldn't do it for the case when $\mathbb{P}(Y>(2-X) \cap X>1)$.